# Mount an existing partition without formatting

Tags: arch-linux, mount, disk

I've installed Arch Linux on `/dev/sda2` and it is marked as `boot`.
But I have all my old files and documents in `/dev/sda1` that is not accessible.

When I run `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`, there is an error:

```
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

How to recover all my old files?

Output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.09 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: HGST HTS545032A7
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe324f148

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 534985522 534983475 255.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *    541278208 625142447  83864240    40G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       534986752 541278207   6291456     3G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

`/dev/sda3` is a swap

Output of `lsblk /dev/sda1`:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda1   8:1    0 255.1G  0 part
```

Output of `file -s /dev/sda1`

```
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=c5c99a23-3374-4e5f-acf0-8ecd014e26cd (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)
```

Output of `e2fsck -f -n /dev/sda1`

```
e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 78142464 blocks
The physical size of the device is 66872934 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? no

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 789314 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Optimize? no

Inode 813861 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower.  Optimize? no

Inode 1322338 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? no

Error reading block 67108896 (Invalid argument) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error? no

Error while scanning inodes (16654338): Can't read next inode
e2fsck: aborted
```

Comment: Next time, please also add that [to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/609072/edit) so that it's easy for everyone to find. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: What does `fsck -n /dev/sda1` return? (The `-n` flag means "no action", so you won't actually be changing anything on the filesystem.)

Comment: Then sda1 has most probably not been unmounted properly last time you used it. @roaima : If mount has not been able to guess what the fstype was, I wonder how standard fsck (which also needs to guess) would. Best would be imho to specify the fstype in the fsck command with the -t option. -t ext4

Comment: Fair enough MC68020. Unviray please try instead `e2fsck -f -n /dev/sda1`

Comment: @roaima : The answer given by the file command is typical of the one given for a logical partition (not starting with DOS/MBR blahblah). In which case, where is the extended partition it belongs to ?

Comment: Unviray you've changed the partition table haven't you. The partition holding your filesystem has (at some point) been shrunk by around 5GB, but the filesystem wasn't shrunk. You might get some of it back. You might not.

Comment: Yes, My old OS (ubuntu) is in `/dev/sda1`. 
When switching to Archlinux , I install it in `/dev/sda2` and I want the `/dev/sda1` mounted in `/home` if it is possible.

Comment: It _was_ in /dev/sda1. You've done the equivalent of tearing out the last 10 pages from a book and throwing them away. The book is now incomplete and of little use to anyone.

Comment: So, `/dev/sda1` is not recoverable and should be formated ?

Comment: No... I wouldn't say that yet, but it will need reformatting at some point. You _might_ be able to get _some_ of your data off it. Maybe someone else can help you with that

Comment: before any sort of fiddling, (which will necessarily involve guessing & rewriting more or less manually several blocks on the disk, if you can find whatever 250G support, first dd if=... of=...

Comment: You have unresolved issues with this partition. You need to run `e2fsck` without `-n`.

Comment: If you want to try to recover data, see what testdisk's deeper search shows. If it shows files, copy to another drive. If not try photorec, but it does not recover full file name, just by type/extension. You have to manually rename. It also finds deleted files. I had saved some text files many times & it recovered all of them, but then had to run compare to old backup copy. Took weeks. Or learned to do better backups. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec See step by step pages for more details on those tools.

Comment: Drop it, i will format it.